# nuxtServerInit with vuex-module-decorators

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Using this approach with Nuxt: https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators#accessing-modules-with-nuxtjs

store/index.ts:

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { initialiseStores } from '~/utils/store-accessor'

const initializer = (store: Store<any>) => initialiseStores(store)

export const plugins = [initializer]
export * from '~/utils/store-accessor'
```

utils/store-accessor.ts:

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import settingsModule from '~/store/settingsModule'

// eslint-disable-next-line
let settingsStore: settingsModule

// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
function initialiseStores(store: Store<any>): void {
  settingsStore = getModule(settingsModule, store)
}

export { initialiseStores, settingsStore }
```

store/settingsModule.ts:

```
import { Action, Module, Mutation, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

@Module({
  name: 'settingsModule',
  namespaced: true,
  stateFactory: true
})
export default class settingsModule extends VuexModule {
  public videos: any[] = []

  @Mutation
  public SAVE_VIDEOS(value: any) {
    this.videos = value
  }

  @Action({ commit: 'SAVE_VIDEOS' })
  public saveVideos(value: any) {
    return value
  }

  // noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
  get videosArray() {
    return this.videos
  }
}
```

How do i actually call `nuxtServerInit()`? If i try inside "store/index.ts":

```
export const actions: ActionTree<any, any> = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('settingsModule/saveVideos', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], { root: true })
  }
}
```

When i load my web-app, nuxt doesn't firing action dispatch.

Comment: you typed `nuxtServerInit({ displatch })` instead of `dispatch`

Comment: @Ifaruki i typed this code manually here, i don't have that typo in actual code, thanks.

Comment: your app is in 'universal' and not 'spa' mode, right? In universal mode, nuxtServerInit should be fired on server-side (but not on client side)

Comment: It's universal. It is firing on the server-side, but nuxt also fires this in a browser under SSR dropdown in a console.

Answer (score 1):

store/index.ts

```
// https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators#accessing-modules-with-nuxtjs
import { Store } from "vuex";
import { Context } from "@nuxt/types";
import { initialiseStores } from "~/utils/store-accessor";
export * from "~/utils/store-accessor";

export const actions = {
    nuxtServerInit(store: Store<any>, context:Context) {
        console.log(store);
        console.log(context);
    }
};
const initializer = (store: Store<any>) => initialiseStores(store);
export const plugins = [initializer];
```

Ordering of the `const` declarations make a difference

utils/store-accessor.ts

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-mutable-exports */
// https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators#accessing-modules-with-nuxtjs
import { Store } from "vuex";
import { getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import HarmonyStoreModule from "~/store/harmony";

let harmonyStore: HarmonyStoreModule;

function initialiseStores(store: Store<any>): void {
    harmonyStore = getModule(HarmonyStoreModule, store);
}

export { initialiseStores, harmonyStore };
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your initializing your stores:

```
import { Store } from "vuex";
import {initialiseStores, settingsStore } from "~/utils/store-accessor";

const initializer = (store: Store<any>) => initialiseStores(store);
export const plugins = [initializer];
export * from "~/utils/store-accessor";

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({}, ctx) {

// do it once more like so.. 
    initialiseStores(ctx.store);

// now just import stores from utils..
    settingsStore.saveVideos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

// NOTE: 
now all server side functions (asyncData, fetch etc..) will work without the need 
for you to initialize stores only because nuxtServerInit is the very first function 
called once server side. You'll need to call initialiseStores(ctx.store) once more client
side for everything to work (client side) correctly. I suggest using the module
nuxtClientInit and do the same.

}}
```